# Non-compact hard Lefschetz theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

For a compact Kaehler manifold $M$, a basic structural result for its de Rham cohomology is the hard Lefschetz theorem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem#Hard_Lefschetz_theorem) or [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hard+Lefschetz+theorem) for an overview of the result.

What happens in the non-compact case? Does the theorem fail, or is it just not understood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard Lefschetz implies Poincaré duality with real coefficients, in particular $H^0\cong H^{2n}$ and for a non-compact connected manifold that *never* happens ($H^{2n}=0$).

For example: $M:=\mathbb{C}P^2\setminus\mathbb{C}P^1$ is contractible, but hard Lefschetz theorem (as stated) should have given an isomorphism between $H^0(M)=\mathbb{R}$ and $H^4(M)=0$.

UPD. Poincaré duality modification for non-compact manifolds (pointed out by BS.)
suggests a Lefschetz-type map $\mu: H_c^{n-k}\to H^{n+k}$ defined by multiplication by $\omega^k$: $H_c^{n-k}\to H_c^{n+k}$ and subsequent composition with the canonical map from $H_c$ to $H$. $\mu$, hovewer, needs not be an isomorphism:

for $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{0\}$ Lefschetz map is identically zero, but $H^{3}=H_c^1$ are one-dimensional.

So, all in all, hard Lefschetz theorem fails for non-compact Kahler manifolds.

Comment: But are these examples K\"ahler manifolds?

Comment: @PierreDubois yes, an open subset of a Kahler manifold is Kahler

Comment: For non-compact manifolds, there is a duality between (de Rham) cohomologies $H^k$ and $H^{n-k}_c$ --- compactly supported.

Comment: @BS. yes, but multiplication by $[\omega]^k$ still won't necessarily realize the isomorphism  $H_c^{n-k}\to H^{n+k}$, e.g. in case when $\omega$ is exact the Lefschetz map is identically zero.
Also cohomology with compact support is not homotopy invariant and doesn't work in analytic/algebraic category, which is a big disadvantage.

Comment: @DmitryK Cohomology with compact support works fine in the algebraic category. Although it doesn't have the same functoriality properties as usual cohomology, it has others.

Comment: The answers of https://mathoverflow.net/q/47852/6451 (about mixed Hodge structures) could perhaps help, at least in the algebraic case.